# How to know which coordinate value is Lat/Lon resp. x/y?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

Consider the following CRS as examples:

```
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326)
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(25832)
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(3857)
```

How can I determine programmatically which axes they have and which axis is latitude/longitude resp. northing/easting resp. x/y if I have a `QgsPoint` geometry in such system with a `.x()` and `.y()` coordinate? I.e. if I have a `QgsPoint(10, 55)` in a EPSG:4326 layer, how can I know programmatically if its `.x()` value `10` is a latitude or a longitude?

The WKT returned by `toWkt()` does sometimes return information about the axes but not for EPSG:4326 plus I am not sure if the order in the returned WKT text is in any way corresponding to the x (first?) and y (second?) coordinates of the geometry:

```
>>> QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326).toWkt()
'GEOGCS["WGS 84",
  DATUM["WGS_1984",
    SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
  PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
  UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]'
```

```
>>> QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(25832).toWkt()
'PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",
GEOGCS["ETRS89",
    DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","25832"]]'
```

```
>>> QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(3857).toWkt()
'PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]'
```

Comment: I would have a try with hasAxesInverted in https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Coordinate/QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html for checking the order.

Comment: That works well! Do you know what the normal case is ("East, North" apparently) and where this is standardized?

Comment: It was "standardized" in many common GIS software that often did not support coordinate systems at all when they were young. The developers were only thinking about the screen coordinates, and it was natural to think that x is left-to-right (longitude or easting) and y is bottom-to-top (latitude or northing). This is sometimes called as "traditional GIS order" https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html#crs-and-axis-order. In many GIS formats (shapefile, PostGIS Well Known Binary etc.) coordinates are also natively saved in this  order independently of the CRS.

Comment: Thanks! I looked into the QGIS source and it really is that simple: it checks if the first axis is "north" (aka "y") and if so, `hasAxisInverted` will return `True`. So if the order is not x/y, then it is inverted.

Comment: Be careful also with x and y. For example the official abbreviation for the north axis in the Gauss-Krüger coordinate systems is "X" https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/21463.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.hasAxisInverted()` method to check against the standard case (which seems to be "east, north", i.e. "x, y").

Examples with a fairly random selection of CRSs:

| EPSG code | hasAxisInverted | Order on epsg.org | Match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25832 | False | e, n | ✓ |
| 31467 | True | n, e | ✓ |
| 3857 | False | e, n | ✓ |
| 7789 | False | x, y, z | ✓ |
| 3034 | True | n, e | ✓ |
| 3035 | True | n, e | ✓ |
| 4936 | False | x, y, z | ✓ |
| 3995 | False | x, y | ✓ |
| 9840 | True | n, e | ✓ |
| 5070 | False | e, n | ✓ |
| 9822 | False | e, n | ✓ |
| 4326 | True | n, e | ✓ |